# Оптимизация таблицы MySQL

Tags: оптимизация, mysql

Как добиться максимальной оптимизации следующей таблицы:

Имеется 3 целочисленных поля, по которым производится поиск записи (эта тройка значений является уникальной для каждой записи), и одно поле `VARBINARY` с динамической длиной, которое принимает массив байт, состоящий от 1 до 200 элементов.

После создания записи могут быть отредактированы данные VARBINARY поля, не меняя его длины.

Comment: сделайте эти три поля как PRIMARY_KEY. Будет индексация автоматическая.

Answer (score 1):

Можно добавить одно поле с первичным ключом, а из трех полей сделать уникальный составной индекс. Первичный ключ - позволит СУБД быстро ориентировать в таблице, а составной индекс выстроит данные. Я советую воспользоваться функцией EXPLAIN. C ее помощью можно будет определить оценить скорость выполнения конкретного вопроса. Для этого нужно перемножить значения строк, которое необходимо для выполнения запроса. НО эта функция поможет вам оценить, будет ли использоваться индекс СУБД в построенном вами запросе для выполнения выборки.

Comment: Суррогатный ключ стоит использовать только ради того, чтобы не использовать объемный индекс в других таблицах.

Если три поля таблицы уникальны и ни одна из таблиц не будет ссылаться на определенную запись в исходной таблице, то эти три поля можно смело использовать в качестве первичного ключа.

Особенно это будет полезно в кластерах. Суррогатный ключ в этом плане не очень хорош